# Quitting after an unwritten deal before accepting job is not fulfilled by company

Tags: applications, quitting

A few months ago I applied for IT manager for my current company. They offered me a notebook (mid-high specification), and agreed for me to take it home. Then we agreed for me to start working the next week, when the notebook would arrive.

Long story short, they ordered me not to take the notebook home again. Note that the previous deal is not written. The reason is just because it's company property. (I acknowledge that)

Soon I will come off the probation period, and asked to sign a 1-year contract to continue working. I already send an application to a different company (and different role) without informing them (yet), and planning not to continue with the contract - the trigger is because they won't fulfill the deal agreed beforehand.

How to quit this job without giving off bad impression both to current job, and next job?

I reckon not taking up the contract is my right, but should I mention the deal, again?
Note that I'm satisfied and happy with my current job, provided they agreed to allow me bring the notebook home. (I'm doing various side jobs that require a relatively high specification, and currently cannot afford to buy one, yet)

Comment: You quit for just that laptop? Why can't u buy it yourself?

Comment: By not allowing you to take the laptop home, they're presumably aware that you can't work from home. Oh noes, now you have some work-life balance.

Comment: He says he currently cannot afford to buy one.

Comment: If you are doing side jobs with company equipment, that could cause some issues for you, could it not? A company laptop is purely for company work. If you are getting jobs on the side, you should have your own gear for that.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that sounds like an answer :)

Comment: You are working as an IT manager and can't afford to buy yourself a laptop? You are being paid far too little or are spending lots of money on other stuff and don't really need the laptop.

Comment: Oh noes, if you want to be a freeloader, you should avoid putting personally identifiable information in your profile. If your boss or someone above reads this, he may *fire* you before you get the chance to quit without leaving a bad impression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm doing various side jobs that require a relatively high
>   specification.

No you're not. At least you shouldn't be.

The notebook is company property. Unless you have explicit permission to use it for non-company purposes, you are probably violating the terms of your contract. In addition, it's fairly common for businesses to state that anything you create/design/produce on company property belongs to the company.

My advice - talk to your employer. There's no harm in explaining your situation and simply asking them if there's another (probably lower-spec) machine that you can borrow for home use. It's in their interest to keep you happy in your job and if it only costs them the temporary loss of one machine, they might not care.

> How to quit this job without giving off bad impression both to current
>   job, and next job?

There is no bad impression. The point of probation periods is so that both the employer and employee are happy with the working arrangements. If you want to leave, then leave. If they're really not expecting you to go, it's probably a good idea to give a polite explanation as to why you're leaving, but in the end it's better for both sides to be straight with each other.